# Which word order produces the more suitable sentence?

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

Which of the following is an appropriate sentence?

1. Only he could see through the trick.
2. Only he could see the trick through.

According to me, the first one is right. Can you explain which one is right or more appropriate?

Also, can I say "He took leave from office because he wanted to go for hitch-hiking," or should I say "He took leave from office because he wanted to go hitch-hiking"? Which version is right and why?

Comment: I'm closevoting for lack of prior reference (plus it should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)). They mean different things. Compare the Cambridge dictionary definitions for [***see through** someone/something*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/see-through-someone-something) and [***see** something **through***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/see-something-through).

Answer (score 2):

The two quoted sentences mean two different things. The first one—

> Only he could see through the trick.

—means that "he" is the only person who wasn't deceived by the trick. The second one—

> Only he could see the trick through.

—means that "he" is the only person who could persevere in ensuring that the trick eventually succeeded. So: two sentence wordings, two distinct sentence meanings.